# Install script will not execute

Tags: magento-1.9, install-script

My module lives at `app/code/local/Mymod/Pinterestimage`.

`etc/config.xml` containts:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mymod_Pinterestimage>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
        </Mymod_Pinterestimage>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <!-- Create Pinterest image attribute using resources-->
        <resources>
            <pinterestimage_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Mymod_Pinterestimage</module>
                    <!-- <class>Mymod_Pinterestimage_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>-->
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </pinterestimage_setup>
        </resources>
        ...
    </global>
    ...
</config>
```

In `app/code/local/Mymod/Pinterestimage/sql/pinterestimage_setup/install-020.php` I have:

```
<?
echo 'Running This Upgrade: '.get_class($this)."\n <br /> \n";
die("Exit for now");
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();
$this->addAttribute(
    'catalog_product',
    'pinterest_image',
    array (
        'group'             => 'Images',
        'type'              => 'varchar',
        'frontend'          => 'catalog/product_attribute_frontend_image',
        'label'             => 'Default Pinterest Image',
        'input'             => 'media_image',
        'class'             => '',
        'source'            => '',
        'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
        'visible'           => true,
        'required'          => false,
        'user_defined'      => false,
        'default'           => '',
        'searchable'        => false,
        'filterable'        => false,
        'comparable'        => false,
        'visible_on_front'  => false,
        'unique'            => false,
    )
);
$installer->endSetup();
```

In the database table `core_resources` I do not see a code column with the attribute Mymod_Pinterestimage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved this by changing:

1. *app/code/local/Mymod/Pinterestimage/sql/**pinterestimage_setup**/install-020.php*

   to...

   *app/code/local/Mymod/Pinterestimage/sql/**Mymod_pinterestimage_setup**/install-020.php*

and

2. <*resources*><*pinterestimage_setup*>

   to... <*resources*><**mymod_pinterestimage_setup**>

Answer (score 3):

You can delete the record "pinterestimage_setup" from the database table `core_resource` instead of changing "pinterestimage_setup" to "mymod_pinterestimage_setup"

Comment: Great answer, if you are developing a custom module, and for some reason you want to re-setup the module you have to do this first, otherwise it will not setup the tables.